# Minimize a complex quadratic subject to two convex quadratic constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

I have the following the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbb{x}\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}}~&||\mathbb{x}^H\mathbb{u}||_2^2-2*Real\{ \mathbb{x^Hu}\}
\\\ subject~to~&\mathbb{x}^Hx\leq P_1
\\\ & \mathbb{x}^HC\mathbb{x}\leq P_2
\end{align}
$P_1$ and $P_2$ are given positive constants. $C$ is a positive-semi-definite matrix. $\mathbb{u}$ is a $N \times 1$ complex vector. As can be seen, constraints are convex. I am not sure if the objective is. Does a closed form exist for this problem? I am familiar with Quadratic Constrained Quadratic Programming and that this problem can be solved using Convex optimization techniques. I was interested in something in the lines of Lagrangian and KKT.

Comment: Were you able to find the dual via KKT? This would help me with my current problem.

Comment: @Dunkel I solved it using a completely different mathematical approach. Please reach out to me at MyUserName@gmail.com